# php json decode bool(true)

Tags: php, json, decode

I have Json array returned from API

```
$json_array = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($json_array);
echo '<br>'.mb_detect_encoding($json_array);`

{"code":"TEXT","name":"/generic/PRODUCT","desc":"/generic/PRODUCT_DESC","productCategory":"/market/prodcats/"}bool(true)
```

ASCII

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(json_decode($json_array));
```

Returns same array not decoded. Any suggestions what could be?

> json_last_error();
>
> Call to undefined function json_last_error() in /var/www/index.php on line 59

Comment: You need to pass the optional parameter `TRUE` to `json_decode()` to return an array.

Comment: You might want to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true to capture the response into a variable instead of printing it to screen.

Comment: Jeff Puckett II thanks alot it worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

By default json_decode function returns stdClass, if you want an array you should send the second parameter equals to True.

```
$json_array = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($json_array);
echo '<pre>'; print_r(json_decode($json_array,TRUE));
```

Comment: no 4EACH, that's not the case,  Jeff Puckett already explained what was the problem. The response wasn't set to a variable, that's why I couldn't convert it to PHP array or stdClass Object.